# Filter products data in magento

Tags: php, magento, migration

I need to **migrate** only **active products** 
i am using the below **code** to get all product collection

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

can anybody tell me how can i filter only **status = enabled** form above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
```